# angular2 and templates - how to do a string replace in routerlink

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an angular2 template syntax that looks like this:

```
<tr  *ngFor="let iter of top_cities">
  <td><a [routerLink]="['test',state, iter.key ]"> {{iter.key | titleCase }}</a></td>
```

HoweverI need to do something like this:

```
<tr  *ngFor="let iter of top_cities">
   <td><a [routerLink]="['test',state, iter.key.replace(' ','-') ]"> {{iter.key | titleCase }}</a></td>
```

That is in the iter I need to replace a city name with a space with a hyphen.  How do I do that?

```
  [routerLink]="['test',state, iter.key.replace(' ','-') ]"
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this not work for you? It works for me. Though you probably want to lower case it also. Also though there may not be many cities with three words, your solution only works for cities with up to two words. For more, you should probably add a method in your component that can use a regex for the replace call. Something like `id.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()`. This will capture multiple spaces. Works fine testing right now

Comment: oh dear I cant believe that worked was trying to show how I would do in python

Answer (score -1):

U can resolve this using a Pipe...

https://angular.io/api/core/PipeTransform

I need take a little help to newbies on angular way.

https://gist.github.com/W3SS/f1dcda48c8f15f6b6cad670093eafd0e

this is my gist with a pipe cloned to sangress ...

good lucky and May the Force be with you !!!

Comment: Please don't just post links - post the relevant documentation and code *in your answer itself*, else it is likely to be deleted for being very low quality.